# Create a item in a libary with SharePoint rest api

Tags: document-library, rest, library, form-library

Is it possible to create item(like .docx or .xsn or ...) in document library or form library in sharepoint 2013 using REST service?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to create *.docx file in document library using REST services.

For more detail you can refer this MSDN article [Files and folders REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_File)

Let me know whether this helped you.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using below mentioned functions you can upload document to Document library.

Here you need to change the below mentioned code according to your needs like here it is mentioned document library name as "Project Documents" so please change it with your library name.

You have to make three calls. The first uploads the file, the second retrieves the list item associated with the file that was just uploaded, and the third sets the field values

```
function uploadDocument() {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert("This browser does not support the HTML5 File APIs");
        return;
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
    var file = element.files[0];
    var parts = element.value.split("\\");
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        alert(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    function addItem(buffer, fileName) {
        var call = uploadDocument(buffer, fileName);
        call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var call2 = getItem(data.d);
            call2.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var item = data.d;
                var call3 = updateItemFields(item);
                call3.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var div = jQuery("#message");
                    div.text("Item added");
                });
                call3.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                });
            });
            call2.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
        });
        call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function uploadDocument(buffer, fileName) {
        var url = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Project Documents')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
            _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: buffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
            }
        });

        return call;
    }

    function getItem(file) {
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });

        return call;
    }

    function updateItemFields(item) {
        var now = new Date();
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Project Documents')/Items(" +
                item.Id + ")",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.Project_x0020_DocumentsItem" },
                Year: now.getFullYear()
            }),
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
                "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });

        return call;
    }

    function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
        var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
        alert("Call failed. Error: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this helps you to solve your problem?